# Statistics: why is this probablility smaller?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

a shipment of goods contains two containers, one container has 300 units and the other container has 700 units.
A supervisor checks 30 units in the first container and he finds $X_1$ broken units and 70 units in the second container where he finds $X_2$. broken units.
which of the following estimators are the best?

$$p_1 = (X_1+X_2)/100 $$
$$p_2 = (3X_1+7X_2)/580 $$

According to the solution $Var(p_1) < Var(p_2)$ , but HOW?

here is what i did.
EDIT: removed because it was nonsens

EDIT2: **ASSUME THAT I AM STUPID**, explain it to me like I am a piece of cabbage, I dont "get" hints.

EDIT:
After some days of work and reading I found out that everything is perfectly solvable if I write $$X_1=30x$$ and $$X_2=70x$$ and solve for var(x).... Thanks noone here I guess... I dont know why you couldnt help me with that, you probably have alot more experience with this.

Comment: Why are you assuming $X_1=x/30$ and $X_2=x/70$? _Dividing_ by $30$ and $70$ makes no sense -- that assumes that we find _more_ broken units among the 30 from the first container than among the 70 from the second one.

Comment: oh... I didnt think... I have tried different ways and i am tired I guess... I have also tried givin $X_1$ = $X_2$ = x but that does not work either... because then $p_1 = x/50$ and $p_2 = x/58$

Comment: What you really should think of is not getting a single _value_ for each of $p_1$ and $p_2$ but finding their _distribution_ under the assumption that all units are broken with the same probability, and independently. Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both binomial distributed.

Comment: yeah, that var(p) = (p*(1-p))/n thing... but I dont understand, I have been working on this since yesterday, reading my statistics book in and out trying to understand the logic... I dont understand this

Comment: " assumption that all units are broken with the same probability, and independently. Then X1 and X2 are both binomial distributed" what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $Var(a X_1 + b X_2) = a^2 Var(X_1) + b^2 Var(X_2)$

Does smaller variance always imply better estimator?

Comment: How does that make $\mu_1$ a smaller estimator? I have worked on this problem for days and would be very happy with a explisit answer

Comment: I mean... your formula would mean $p_1 = (1/100)^2*X_1 + (1/100)^2*X_2$ and $p_2 = (5/580)^2*X_1 + (7/580)^2*X_2$... I dont see how I can come to the conclusion that $var(p_1) < var(p_2)$ based on that

Comment: Your "hint" did not help me much, but it is the only one avaiable and I solved it anyway so I gave you the "accept answer" thing.

Comment: @KaizervonMaanen Sorry that it didn't help. You can always answer your own answer and accept it. Feel free to "unaccept" this answer.